# How to format a JSON object to send it through header in python?

Tags: python, json, post

The API I'm looking to interact with ask for a 'key', a 'nonce' and a 'signature' and here is how it must be build:

> "The signature is generated by creating a SHA256 HMAC using the Bitso API Secret on the concatenation of nonce + HTTP method + requestPath + JSON payload (no ’+’ signs in the concatenated string) and hex encode the output. The nonce value should be the same as the nonce field in the Authorization header. The requestPath and JSON payload must, of course, be exactly as the ones used in the request."

The problem is when I try to send a json payload. If I send the json payload as a dict, the program says the it cant be concatenated whit strings and when I send it as a string the server response says that the nonce is invalid.

**How should I build the json payload?**

Here's my code sending the payload as a string:

```
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import requests

bitso_key = "xxxxxxxxxx"
bitso_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
nonce =  str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
http_method = "POST"
request_path = "/v3/orders/"
json_payload = """{'book':'xrp_mxn','side':'sell','type':'market','major':'0.5'}"""

print(json_payload)

# Create signature
message = nonce+http_method+request_path+json_payload
print(message)
signature = hmac.new(bitso_secret.encode('utf-8'),message.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
# Build the auth header
auth_header = 'Bitso %s:%s:%s' % (bitso_key, nonce, signature)

# Send request
response = requests.get("https://api.bitso.com/v3/orders/", headers={"Authorization": auth_header})

print (response.content)
```

Here's the response:

```
b'{"success":false,"error":{"code":"0201","message":"Nonce o credenciales inv\\u00e1lidas"}}'
```

And if I send it as a dict:

```
json_payload = {'book':'xrp_mxn','side':'sell','type':'market','major':'0.5'}
```

Here's the response:

```
message = nonce+http_method+request_path+json_payload
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str
```

Here's the doc page of the api: https://bitso.com/api_info#place-an-order

Comment: Is that the *response* or a **local** TypeError? Anyway, the original JSON string shown is **not JSON** and so is expected to fail (JSON keys are *always* surrounded by double quotes; anything else is invalid JSON).

Comment: Use *proper JSON encoding* to generate proper JSON (instead of the non-JSON string shown). Then use this *as text*, for both the signature and request body. Eg: `json_text = json.dumps(object_to_send..)`.

Comment: @user2864740 The TypeError is a local error due to the dict + string concatenation. And if its not a JSON, how a JSON should look?

Comment: http://json.org/ - explains the JSON syntax.

Comment: Thank you I will check that function, it seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not concatenate a string with a `dict`, but you can convert your `dict` to a json string using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library:

```py
import json
import time

nonce = str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
http_method = "POST"
request_path = "/v3/orders/"

payload = {'book': 'xrp_mxn', 'side': 'sell', 'type': 'market', 'major': '0.5'}
json_payload = json.dumps(payload)

message = nonce + http_method + request_path + json_payload
print(message)
```

You get:

```
1568403950209POST/v3/orders/{"major": "0.5", "type": "market", "book": "xrp_mxn", "side": "sell"}
```

Comment: I already done it and the response from the server still the same: ' nonce o credenciales invalidas''. Let me check the nonce, the credentials and the function dump.

Answer (score 0):

As user2864740 and Laurent LAPORTE commented what was wrong with the code was the encoding a string into JSON format but also the code I was using was from a older version in the official docs of the API so I check the newer ones and format the dict into a JSON and done.